# JFace Labelprovider needs info from parent tree item

Tags: eclipse, jface

My labelprovider has to add a suffix to the text depending on the parent item in the tree. Think of a tree of this structure:

Component A0

-> Component X1 (A-Type)

Component B0

—> Component X1 (B-Type)

—> Component X2

Component X1 is twice in the tree, and its suffix needs to make clear that it's a child of A or B.

Anyone has an idea? Thanks

Comment: Try a Decorator instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the `ITreeContentProvider` of the tree viewer available to your label provider you can ask its `getParent()` method for the parent of the element for which the label is to be computed.

Comment: The problem is that my domain object cannot give a correct answer as for Component X1 both Comp. A0 and B0 are parents. Only the tree item knows, but I don't know how to get information from there.

Comment: But your content provider could be enhanced to give you that answer: in the least case the `getChildren()` implementation could maintain a map of elements and their respective parent. With this map `getParent()` can lookup the parent for a given element.